Are Keepy Uppys a useful tactic in Football?
So, I'm aware that footballers will often use Keepy Uppys as a training device, learning better ball control etc. but I'm not sure I've ever seen it used on the pitch.
I can, however, see how they could be useful, keeping the ball out of reach and making it difficult to take possession without making contact and allowing a player to line up a shot with less interference.
I don't think it should be outside the rules even if the player uses their head and chest, there's no contact with their hands.
So is this used in the professional game? and if not, why not?

As you can challenge a player shoulder to shoulder, keeping possession of the ball with tricky moves such as these is almost impossible, and often useless. When challenged from the back, it might work for a couple of moves (because your body protects the ball), but still...
